# PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception insert formula in field

Tags: php, phpexcel

My code:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($index)->setCellValue('A1', '=SUM(2;2)');
```

error:

> ## PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception
>
> A1 -> Formula Error: An unexpected error occured (extensions\phpexcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php:300)
>
> #0 \extensions\phpexcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php(754): PHPExcel_Cell->getCalculatedValue()
>   #1 extensions\phpexcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\Worksheet.php(373): PHPExcel_Worksheet->calculateColumnWidths()
>   #2 \extensions\phpexcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\Worksheet.php(80): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007_Worksheet->_writeCols(Object(PHPExcel_Shared_XMLWriter), Object(PHPExcel_Worksheet))
>   #3 extensions\phpexcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007.php(304): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007_Worksheet->writeWorksheet(Object(PHPExcel_Worksheet), Array, false)
>   #4

Answer (score 1):

in '= SUM (2;2)'

change ; for ,

'= SUM (2,2)'